# create folder into sd card programmatically

Tags: android

i am trying to put audio mp3 file into Awesome Music folder, but always getting under Music directory.

see below screenshot:

[image]

code i have written:

```
private static String fileName = "MyMusic";
    private static final String MY_URL = "http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3";
static File mediaStorageDir ;

 // folder name
                mediaStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),
                                "/Awesome Music/");

                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");                  
                    }
                }

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mediaStorageDir + fileName + ".mp3");
```

**Questions:**

1. why its not storing mp3 into Awesome Music folder ?
2. why its showing Awesome Music as prefix of song name ?

I am using [this](http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-downloading-mp3-to-sd-card.html) tutorial

**complete code:**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static String fileName = "MyMusic";
private static final String MY_URL = "http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3";

private Button download;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
static File mediaStorageDir ;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);

    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(MY_URL);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type:
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

public void downloadStreams() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        File outputFile = new File(MY_URL, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error: " + e);
    }
    Log.v("log_tag", "Check: ");
}

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // folder name
            mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),
                            "/Awesome Music/");
            Log.d("mediaStorageDir", mediaStorageDir.toString());

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");                  
                }
            }
            Log.d("before>>fileName", fileName);
            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mediaStorageDir + fileName + ".mp3");
            Log.d("after>>fileName", fileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

}
```

}

**Log:-**

```
D/mediaStorageDir(22616): /storage/sdcard0/Music/Awesome Music
D/before>>fileName(22616): MyMusic
D/after>>fileName(22616): MyMusic
```

Comment: The code seems right. Could you log the path of `mediaStorageDir` and make sure that its correct? Also, could you provide the resulting file name?

Comment: Have you used **MY_URL** anywhere???

Comment: Change here **mediaStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)+
                                "/Awesome Music/");**

Comment: @Vishnu  Log - D/mediaStorageDir(18445): /storage/sdcard0/Music/Awesome Music

Comment: @Moon : Also, what's the filename?

Comment: i posted whole code along with log

Comment: i tried every solution but issue is still there

Comment: @Moon Check out my updated answer and try out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)`

use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Answer (score 1):

you are downloading some mp3 files right,ok then please try this code

```
URL url = new URL("your url");
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
File gallery = new File("/sdcard/Awesome Music/");

    String filename="somefilename.mp3"

if (!gallery.exists()) {
                gallery.mkdir();
            }
            String datafile = "/sdcard/Awesome Music/" + filename;
            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(datafile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;


                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

Hope this will help you,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `,` with `+` to have the full path of the parent folder in which your files will be stored

```
mediaStorageDir = new File(
  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)+
                            "/Awesome Music/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting that folder inside music directory because you have written code to get the path of that music directory.

```
 Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
```

If you want to create folder directly into the SDcard then you have to just write

```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

which will give you the path upto the sdcard.

**EDITED:**

If you want to put your file inside the folder which resides in music directory then try as below:

```
  mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
    + File.separator + "Awesome Music");
```

Change your code as below:

```
     // folder name
        mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),
                        "/Awesome Music/");
        Log.d("mediaStorageDir", mediaStorageDir.toString());

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");                  
            }
        }
         String filename=mediaStorageDir + fileName + ".mp3";//String contains file name
         File newfile=new File(mediaStorageDir,filename);

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
        Log.d("after>>fileName", fileName);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

Check out my blog [Android External storage structure](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/01/android-storage-system-to-access-path.html) which will guide you about the structure of android folders.

Comment: you are misunderstand the question op wants write file into Awesome folder which sub folder of Music but it is writing into its parent Music not directly into Sdcard directory

Comment: I don't think that is the issue here. The resulting file path is `/sdcard/Music/Awesome Music My Music.mp3` and not `/sdcard/Music/Awesome Music/My Music.mp3`. He does want that folder to be inside `Music`.

Comment: @kalyanpvs No i didn't I am updating my answer.

Comment: @Vishnu from first line of OP **i am trying to put audio mp3 file into Awesome Music folder, but always getting under Music directory**. means its inside Awesome folder right??

Comment: i am following this tutorial : http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-downloading-mp3-to-sd-card.html